# Slow Web site speeds

Tags: performance, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I am currently trying to fix some speed issues on a site for a client (not built by myself), but can't figure out how to increase the speed of the site. It is built on WordPress and I have tried multiple things to get it working - to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: there's not much information here to go on. Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: I do. If it helps it is using the Vantage premium theme...

Comment: Then start analyzing and find where the performance bottlenecks are. Is it in the javascript running clientside, or serverside? Is it in the amount of data being transferred to the user?

Comment: Do you know how I can do that? Performance optimization is not something I'm knowledgeable on unfortunately! What software can I use to find the bottlenecks?

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of information here.
It the WP Loop.

The 7.69 second load time for index.php

It's the WP plug-ins in the WP Loop that are causing the long load time.

If the site is static then just save the pages and serve them as static.

It appears the waterfall is cut off.  somewhere down below that there is very likely a CSS or font file being loaded that is delaying the Start Render.

**Correction**, this page is a basket case and it should be redesigned from the ground up.